# Extracting day, month and year from calendar tables

Tags: jquery

I am working on a booking system built in CodeIgniter. I have modified the Calendar library slightly to show only the four next weeks. I want the user to be able to choose check in and check out dates. When the corresponding calendar shows, the user pushes the date, and the value is stored in a hidden input, using JQuery. If it is late in a month, there might be two months showing, in other words two calendar tables.

What is the best way to store the date using JQuery? The table cells is only showing the day, while a table heading is showing "month year".

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a javascript `Date` object.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

**EDIT**: To create a date object

```
var date = new Date(2011, 6, 4); //Assigns July 4th, 2011 to date var
```

**EDIT**: If you want to get the values from cells as you asked:

```
var year = $("th#year").text();
var month = parseInt($("td#month").text(), 10)-1; //-1 Cause January is 0
var day = $("td#day").text();
var date = new Date(year, month, day);
```

Comment: Yes, but how will the created object "know" both the day, month and year, when it is "stored" in different cells?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just replace those numbers for your collected data from cells.

Comment: I might have been unclear. The issue is not in what "format" to save the date, but rather how to gather and combine the information. The month and year is in a th-tag, the day in a td-tag. How can I extract all the information when it's contained in different tags

Comment: I've updated my post to do what you just asked. Hope thishelps